# Windows 8.1 split screen 2 desktops

Tags: windows-8.1, split-window

Sometime ago, I accidentally dragged the top of the desktop and found out I can actually drag it. I didn't even know what feature it is but I find it funny,
[image: Windows 8.1 drag and drop]
Until today I lookup for the name of this feature which is 'split screen'. But when I split screen, one side is the desktop, other side can only the 'New Windows 8 App' like 'PC settings', 'New Calculator'. I wonder if I can create 2 desktops with split screen which I actually need. (I think split screen to use 'PC settings' or Calculator is ridiculous) 
[image: Windows 8.1 split screen calculator]

Comment: Windows doesn’t support what you want

Comment: @Ramhound well it does.